# Why does mercurial "hg log --style paper" give me "permission denied" error?

Tags: mercurial

hg log works.
hg log --style does not work.

```
C:\temp\myhg>"c:\program files\mercurial\hg" log

changeset:   0:9c62e300d833
user:        Administrator@biostar
date:        Wed Oct 21 04:57:41 2009 -0500
summary:     124 my first commit

C:\temp\myhg>"c:\program files\mercurial\hg" log --style paper
abort: Permission denied: c:\program files\mercurial\templates\paper
```

As long as you're reading, here's the big picture:   I want to get log format in an easy-to-parse format.  If I use a --template {files} with the the log command, and if there are spaces in the filenames, the output isn't friendly to parsing.  So, according to the docs, I need to use a "style".   But, I can't even get as far as using the styles that install with Mercurial.

I did a vanilla install of Mercurial on Windows XP and have been able to run the init, add, commit, and log commands with no problems.

Comment: I tried this code and have the same problem.

Comment: I tried it on a Mac, and I get "abort: Is a directory" ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

AFAIK, html template sets like 'paper' are designed for being used from hgweb. I don't know how to use them from command line.

What you can do: write a style that would be easy to parse.

To use a style you need to have a file named `map-cmdline.<style>` in templates subdirectory of your Hg installation. [Here](http://www.jaharmi.com/2008/11/30/list_changed_files_in_a_mercurial_repository_with_a_custom_output_style) is the sample of creating template for custom log report. [Here](http://hgbook.red-bean.com/read/customizing-the-output-of-mercurial.html) is a chapter on styles from HgBook.

Hope this will help you.

Comment: With Doug's hint, I happened to figure out the map-cmdline part before reading your answer.   The chapter on styles in the HgBook doesn't even mention the "map-cmdline" part.   If you start with the "From templates to styles" part, you would think you could just create a file with any name, any location....

Answer (score 2):

For me, `hg help templating` says:

> Three styles are packaged with Mercurial: default (the style used when no explicit preference is passed), compact and changelog.

Perhaps something needs to be done to enable the `paper` style? I'm not sure.

Comment: Nope, there's no `paper` style, it's a theme for the web interface :-)